# How it can be recognized that something touches the camera or finger is touched in android?

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to know how it can be recognized that something is taped to the Camera in Android?

Any help please!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to invoke onInterceptTouchEvent() method. 
please check its syntax and more information [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29).

Comment: I'm not working with ViewGroup, onIntercepttouchEvent() belongs to ViewGroup. Then how can I recognize something is tapped to camera? Please don't mind.....Very new to Android.