# Is there onListItemTouch method in listview

Tags: android, listview

I know onListItemClick method to handle click listener as below.

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
}
```

But if I want to handle touch listener.
While item be touched, I want to get the position.
But not do in onListItemClick.
How can I do in ListView?
Is there any method such above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to invoke `onInterceptTouchEvent()` method

Please check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096005/how-it-can-be-recognized-that-something-touches-the-camera-or-finger-is-touched/9096098#9096098).

Answer (score 2):

Use `AbsListView.onTouchEvent()`

You have to subclass the ListView to use it though.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)